# Copy formula containing sheet reference to another sheet and keep relative value of sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I am using Excel for macOS (Version 16.8) and have a workbook that contains 12 worksheets - each is a month (January, February, etc), each contains details of income and expenditure for that month but I want each also to show cumulative to date. So a formula in B2 in March will be `=February!B2+March!A2`. However, if I copy this formula to B2 in April, it now shows `=February!B2+April!A2`.

How do I keep the relative position, i.e., B2 in April should be `=March!B2+April!A2` without having to manually alter the sheet ref in every cell every time I copy them over to the next sheet?

Comment: Can you use VBA?

Comment: I'm thinking with formulas you'll need a lookup talbe and `INDIRECT`. Otherwise, reconfigure your spreadsheets so that pivot tables become an option.

Comment: Please try INDIRECT("'"&"April"&"'!"&"A2")

Comment: Thank you for comments.  I've never used VBA.  I will try to get my head around the INDIRECT function.